# Are Generalized Involution Varieties hyperlane sections of Generalized Severi Brauer Varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, motives

Let  $A$ be a central, simple algebra of degree $2n$ with orthogonal involution $\sigma$.

Let SB$(A)$ the Severi-Brauer variety, which is the variety of left ideals of reduced dimension ***one*** in $A$.

The involution variety Inv$(A,\sigma)= \{ I \in $SB$(A)$ $|$ $\sigma(I)I = 0\}$ is known to be a hyperplane section of SB$(A)$.

We define a generalized SB$(A)_{l,n}$ as the variety of left ideals in $A$ of reduced dimension $l$, when $deg(A) = n$. In an analogue way one can define a generalized involution variety Inv$(A,\sigma)_{l,n}$.

I asked myself, if for $l$ other than $1$, Inv$(A,\sigma)_{l,n}$ is a hyperplane section of SB$(A)_{l,n}$. Calculating the dimensions i think i found that this is *not* possible. However we still can ask

**Question:** For central, simple algebras $A,B$ of degrees $n,2m$, and for $\sigma$ beeing an orthogonal involution on $B$. Can there be $l,k$ such that
 Inv$(B,\sigma)_{k,2m}$ is a hyperplane section of SB$(A)_{l,n}$ ?

What inspired me to think about such things is a result from

D. Krashen - Zero cycles on homogeneous varieties,

stating that for $A$ of degree $4$ and $B$ of degree $6$ there is an *isomorphism* between 
 Inv$(B,\sigma)_{1,6}$ and SB$(A)_{2,4}$.

Comment: If you had an isomorphism of $\text{Inv}(B,\sigma)_{k,2m}$ and $\text{SB}(A)_{\ell,n}$, resp. a hyperplane section thereof, then after an etale extension of your original base, you would have an isomorphism between the orthogonal Grassmannian of isotropic $k$-dimensional subspaces in a vector space of dimension $2m$ and the Grassmannian of $\ell$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space, resp. a hyperplane section thereof.  As Krashen points out, this is actually the case for $(k,2m)=(1,6)$ and $(\ell,n)=(2,4)$, i.e., $\text{Grass}(2,4)$ is a quadric fourfold . . .

Comment: . . . For the dimensions to work out, you need that $k(4m-3k-1)/2$ equals $\ell(n-\ell)$, resp. equals $\ell(n-\ell) - 1$.  Then you can also compute the dimension of the Lie algebra of infinitesimal automorphisms of both sides.  For the orthogonal Grassmannian, it is the dimension of the special orthogonal group, $m(2m-1)$.  For the Grassmannian, it is the dimension of the special linear group $n^2-1$.  For a hyperplane section that happens to be homogeneous (so that $h^1$ of the tangent bundle equals $0$), the dimension is $n^2-\binom{n}{\ell}$.

Comment: I tried to find other solutions of the two Diophantine equations from my comment above, and it looks to me like there are very few solutions (maybe none, beyond the case $(k,2m)=(1,6)$ and $(\ell,n)=(2,4)$).  So that might settle your question.

Comment: I didnt have the time yet to do any calculations using computers. What did you use to figure that out?

Comment: I do not know understand your last comment.

Comment: I was under the assumption that you used a computer, instead of doing anything by hand.

Comment: No, I did not use any computer.